# Mouse + network turned off after suspend

Tags: debian, gnome3, suspend, hibernate

(After upgrade from Debian Wheezy to Jessie), my mouse is not turning on again, when I wake up my computer (from suspend-to-ram sleep).

Is there something that I can add to /etc/pm/... ? gnome-control-center and gnome-tweak-tool have no options.

Also my network is turned off, but this is also so case when booting, so might be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

**suggestions:**

`modprobe -r i2c-hid; modprobe i2c-hid;` from

- http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=128952

`modprobe -r psmouse; modprobe psmouse;` from

- https://matoski.com/article/debian-touchpad-not-working/ ;
- https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad#Touchpad_does_not_work_after_resuming_from_hibernate.2Fsuspend

When anything from above works, automate it in a file in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` as shown in question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508929/touchpad-unresponsive-on-resume-from-sleep-on-debian-8

**similar questions:**

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41508929/touchpad-unresponsive-on-resume-from-sleep-on-debian-8/65886286
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/924074/ubuntu-touchpad-usb-mouse-click-event-not-working
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/862244/ubuntu-16-04-on-macbook-air-2009-wifi-suspend-and-touch-pad